# Mostrar dados da BD

Tags: php

Estou criando um site de filmes que deve mostrar os trailers e tal. Quero que ao adicionar na base de dados algum filme o script organize a tela dinamicamente.

Exemplo: na base de dados vamos ter nome do filme, foto e trailer.

Como devo começar? Se não puderem me ajudar a fazer, pelo menos me digam o que procurar.

[image: Deve ficar assim]

Comment: Você quer dizer alguma forma de verificar na base de dados se há alterações e então ele remover ou adicionar os filmes sem recarregar a página?

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "organizar"?

Comment: Experimente com [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) consegue fazer isso tudo.

Comment: Se você estiver querendo organizar os dados fisicamente no banco de dados, tenta criar alguns index em suas tabelas.  Tenta detalhar melhor a sua pergunta, pois, está faltando informações e causando ambiguidade

Comment: Vou postar o que expliquei aqui >>> http://pastebin.com/bbtRiiL8

Comment: Obrigadoo Marcos Vinicios!! era bem isso que eu queria hehehe!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leve em consideração que ao atualizar sua base de dados, os dados já irão vir atualizados quando exibirem a sua consulta de filmes... Agora, tudo depende de como você está fazendo pra exibir seus dados, para organizar a tabela automaticamente de acordo com a `qtdDeRegistros` que você deve exibir em cada linha, você pode fazer desse modo:

```
$varConsulta = ConsultaFilmes();
    $i=0;
    if ($varConsulta) {
    echo "<table style='margin-left:2%;'><tr>";
        foreach ($varConsulta as $lin) {
            $linhas .= "<td style='vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;'>Filme<br />[IMAGEM][INFORMAÇÕES REFERENTES AO FILME]</td>";

            echo $linhas;

            $i++;
            //Aqui é feito a mágica!!
            if ($i % $qtdDeRegistros == 0) {
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
            }
        }

        echo "</tr></table>";
    }else{
        echo "<h3> Nenhum filme dísponivel.</h3>";
    }
}
```